# XCUITest XCUIElementQuery all non-staticText elements are missing in modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcuitest

I have a modal view for iPad which is wrapped by UIButton

```
UIButton *fullScreenButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[_helper ownerView].bounds];
    fullScreenButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
#ifdef _UI_TEST
    fullScreenButton.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
    fullScreenButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"fullScreenButton";
#endif
```

When I try to get query structure of the modal view I can see staticTexts only. Other controls like tables, cells, otherElements are not visible for me.

The problem happened after migration xcode 10.3 -> xcode 11.1 and ios12 -> ios13.

It seems to me the reason of the problem is UIButton wrapper for modal view, but I do not have access to replace UIButton with another wrapper.

Is anybody have ideas how to detect and fix problem?